# Decode scrambled UART bytes from serialport RS485

Tags: serial-port, uart, rs485

I'm connecting two PCs (one Windows, one Linux) with two RS485 Adapters (A,B,C wire). The problem is.. although both devices are set identically to "19200 8N1" ... I cannot get a working connection, because the bytes arrive in only one direction and the content is scrambled somehow.

I open the device by `stty -F /dev/ttyS1 19200 cs8 -parity` and do an `echo 12345 > /dev/ttyS1` and on windows I always receive the same amount of bytes but **scrambled** data. With this I receive `0x67 0xb3 0xb2 0x59 0xd9 0xbd`. When I do the opposite and send something from windows and try to read in linux I receive nothing ( `cat /dev/ttyS1` or `od -x < /dev/ttyS1`).

Can I somehow figure out what's wrong with the connection by trying to decode how the data is scrambled? Is some sort of UART crypto-analysis possible to figure out wrong settings? Or any ideas what is wrong here?

Comment: The bit patterns are too wildly off.  I'd look for an electrical problem, starting with proper bus termination.  And never skimp on error checking, you ought to get a lot of frame and parity errors.

Comment: Try transmitting from Linux pc with a default baud rate.I guess it is 115200.